# Getting values from Rails database to use in Ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a page that takes user input in a form and saves it to a database in rails. I now need to use those input values in a ruby application I wrote and placed in /lib/, which will generate some new values that I need to store in another database to return it to elements on my page.

I currently have the ruby application taking values from a prompt then using the gets.chomp method, this is just a placeholder until I learn how to use the stored values.

I'm new to back-end programming but here's my controller that I'm using to store the inputs:

**colours_controller.rb**

```
class ColoursController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @colour = Colour.new
  end
  def create
    @colour = Colour.new(colour_params)
    if @colour.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Error."
    end
  end
  private
  def colour_params
    params.require(:colour).permit(:hue, :sat, :luma, :number)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that the inputs are stored in the database, you can easily query them from anywhere in your application using `Colour.find...` or any of its likes.

However, here are few things to note when using a file in `lib` directory:

1. Always add all files in the lib directory to autoload path eg `config.autoload_paths += [config.root.join('lib')]`
2. For new files to be autoloaded afterwards, makes sure the name of the file and the class/module it contains are the same. That means if a file is named `lib/colour_paint.rb`, the module should be `module ColourPaint; end`

Comment: For rails 5, use `config.eager_load_paths`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them as arguments:

For example: say in your ruby file you have a class called `foo` with a method `bar` and it looks like this:

Foo.rb

```
class Foo

  def bar(colour)
    # do something
  end

end
```

in your ColoursController.rb

```
def create
  @colour = Colour.new(colour_params)
  if @colour.save
    foo = Foo.new # instatiate an instance of the foo class
    foo.bar(@colour) # call the bar method and pass the colour variable
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Error."
  end
end
```

Comment: colour is @colour in my controller?

Comment: Thats what you have posted in your OP